# TYPO3, Realurl, News: I am not getting right

Tags: realurl

I have a pretty straightforward Realurl 2.0 + News configuration, still it does not work as it should.

I get something like

```
http://mydomain/list-news-page/single-news-page/news/single-news-title/News/?tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&cHash=5f96d3b6bebd41076d2f752ea4d068d4
```

and I wish to get rid of the `/News/?tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&cHash=5f96d3b6bebd41076d2f752ea4d068d4` section. My `typo3conf/realurl.autoconf.php` sets:

```
'postVarSets' => 
     array (
       '_DEFAULT' => 
               array (
                'news' => 
                    array ( 
                          array(  'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',  ),
                          array(  'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
            ),
                 0 => 
                 array (  
    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
    'lookUpTable' => 
    array (
      'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
      'id_field' => 'uid',
      'alias_field' => 'title',
      'useUniqueCache' => 1,
      'useUniqueCache_conf' => 
      array (
        'strtolower' => 1,
        'spaceCharacter' => '-',

 ), ), ), ), ), )
```

I also have

```
 [globalVar = GP:L =0]
 ....
 config.defaultGetVars {
    tx_news_pi1 {
            controller=Notizie
            action=Dettaglio
    }
 }
[global]
```

but it does not seem to work.

Lastly, if I unset `Enable automatic configuration [basic.enableAutoConf]`, pages not rendered.

TYPO3 6.2.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

1st: Don't translate the actions itself, so the config should be

```
config.defaultGetVars {
        tx_news_pi1 {
                controller=News
                action=detail
        }
}
```

2nd: Take a look at the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html).

You need to map the news uid to the title by using

```
array(
    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
    'lookUpTable' => array(
        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'id_field' => 'uid',
        'alias_field' => 'title',
        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                'strtolower' => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
        ),
        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'autoUpdate' => 1,
        'expireDays' => 180,
    )
)
```

Comment: @@Georg Thanks, I need to find some spare time and check. I'll be back.

Comment: @George I guess I just forgot to thank you. Indeed i looked at the manual and it worked. Now, I am updating to 7.6.21, news 4.2.1,  and I have issue with the first above again: how do I get a speaking url with italian 'dettaglio' instead that default 'detail'? Thanks